# What are the origins of the A,E,I,O notation for the four types of categorical proposition?

Tags: logic, history-of-philosophy

The labels A, E, I, and O are traditionally given to the four types of categorical proposition.

Each is one of the first two vowels in the Latin words *affirmo* (I affirm) or *nego* (I deny), a usage that is said [*] to have originated in mediaeval times. It doesn't appear in Aristotle.

What more specifically is known about the origins of this notation? For example, are there any good candidates for the first known user? What was the earliest recorded use? Where? In what century? In which monastic rule?

Note

* For example by Robert Paul Churchill in his *Logic: An Introduction* (1990), 2nd ed., p.144.